# why smartphones become laggey and slow with time?

Tags: performance

I found a lot of info about how to make my smartphone faster but I couldn't find the reason for smartphones lowliness.

- I found that you should move apps to SD Card (if you have one)
- Don't use a lot of widgets, try not to use too much home screens.
- Remove apps that you don't use. Turn off animation.

And more stuff like this.

But what makes the phone become slow with time?

Answer (score 0):

Same reason a PC becomes slow over time. A lot of crap ends up on the system. For instance; even when you uninstall apps many of them many times leave something behind. The internal android DB becomes full and becomes harder to search because of the large amount of data.

Comment: Is their a good app that can clean this app (with root)?

Comment: There are apps. But I never used any of them so I couldn't tell you